# Function only works when called through chrome console

Tags: javascript, html

I've got a JavaScript function that's supposed to be executed when an HTML button is clicked. The HTML for the form is

```
<form id="inputData">
   Email:<br>
   <input id="email" type="email" name="email"><br>
   Username:<br>
   <input id="username" type="text" name="username"><br>
   Password:<br>
   <input id="password" type="password" name="password"><br>
   <input id="submit" type="submit" value="submit" onClick="getData()">
</form>
```

The related js code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getData() {
  var input = document.getElementById("inputData");
  var email = input[0].value;
  var user = input[1].value;
  var pass = input[2].value;
  sendData(user,email,pass)
}

function sendData(user,email,pass) {
  var fireRef = firebase.database().ref("users/" + user);
  fireRef.set({
    emailAddress: email,
    password: pass,
  });
}
</script>
```

In debugger mode, the function gets executed when the `submit` button is clicked, and there are no errors, all of the form data is properly collected, yet the data never gets sent to the Firebase database. However, if i call the `sendData` function through the console and manually provide data in the arguments, it works perfectly. Can anyone think of why this might be happening?

Comment: debug your code ... what are values of `email`, `user` and `pass` you are passing to `sendData` - given your comments, the obvious place to look is in `getData` - you'll also need to learn what a `submit` button does in a form, and you'll need to `prevent` this `Default` action somehow

Comment: Like I said in the question, I did debug it and the values of email, user, and pass are all correct.

Comment: Like I said in the second half of the comment, learn what a `submit` button does, and how to `prevent` the `Default` behaviour of said button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onClick` event isn't triggering

try

```
<form id="inputData" onsubmit="getData()">
   Email:<br>
   <input id="email" type="email" name="email"><br>
   Username:<br>
   <input id="username" type="text" name="username"><br>
   Password:<br>
   <input id="password" type="password" name="password"><br>
   <input id="submit" type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: you'll still need to `prevent` the `Default` behaviour of a `submit` `event`